# Why is Users index page empty (no users loaded) in production? Works locally. Rails 7 + Railway.app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

I have a Rails 7 app deployed on Railway.app. Admin users can access a User index page. The User index is working fine locally, but when deployed the page is empty (the page loads, but no users are listed).

Based on the logs, none of the actions in the controller are being called in production, even though they are in local server.

**Local server logs:**

```
Started GET "/en/users" for ::1 at 2022-11-08 13:38:38 +0200
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `admin_user'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Count (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmed" = $1  [["confirmed", true]]
  ↳ app/views/users/index.html.erb:4
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmed" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["confirmed", true], ["LIMIT", 30], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  ↳ app/views/users/index.html.erb:7
  Rendered collection of users/_user.html.erb [30 times] (Duration: 4.6ms | Allocations: 3858)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 11.0ms | Allocations: 6653)
  Rendered layouts/_bootstrap_cdn.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 16)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (Duration: 7.3ms | Allocations: 5483)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 15)
  Rendered shared/_search_bar.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 24)
  Rendered user/_session_manager.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 366)
  Rendered shared/_search_modal.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 592)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 1355)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 27)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 158)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 23.8ms | Allocations: 15919)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 23.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 17431)
```

**Production server logs:**

```
I, [2022-11-08T11:39:47.740716 #19]  INFO -- : [8cc8cc81-a68c-4ae6-80a8-a68b31ae0a34] Started GET "/en/users" for 79.183.112.167 at 2022-11-08 11:39:47 +0000
I, [2022-11-08T11:39:47.741782 #19]  INFO -- : [8cc8cc81-a68c-4ae6-80a8-a68b31ae0a34] Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
I, [2022-11-08T11:39:47.741846 #19]  INFO -- : [8cc8cc81-a68c-4ae6-80a8-a68b31ae0a34]   Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
I, [2022-11-08T11:39:47.753841 #19]  INFO -- : [8cc8cc81-a68c-4ae6-80a8-a68b31ae0a34]   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.9ms | Allocations: 414)
I, [2022-11-08T11:39:47.758103 #19]  INFO -- : [8cc8cc81-a68c-4ae6-80a8-a68b31ae0a34]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 8.2ms | Allocations: 2537)
I, [2022-11-08T11:39:47.758466 #19]  INFO -- : [8cc8cc81-a68c-4ae6-80a8-a68b31ae0a34] Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 6.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms | Allocations: 3549)
```

**contollers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :show
  before_action :admin_user, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.where(confirmed: true).paginate(page:params[:page])
  end

  private

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url, status: :see_other) unless
      current_user && current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**views/users/index.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h2>All users</h2>

<%= will_paginate(@users) %>

  <ul class="users">
    <%= render @users %>
  </ul>

<%= will_paginate(@users) %>
```

**views/users/_user.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
```

Comment: The calls to the will_paginate helper should include the collection you're gonna paginate as a parameter: will_paginate(@users).

Comment: Fixed that and updated the question above. Didn't solve my issue though.

Comment: Did you create any users in the production db?

Comment: Yes I have two users, an admin and non-admin user. I am able to sign in and see profile (show) pages for both users. I can also see them in the console via User.all

Comment: @Rebecca are those users in production "confirmed"? You are applying a filter here "where(confirmed: true)". The rest of the posted code seems fine to me.

Comment: @markets - you get the prize. I just came here to post that I figured out the issue and it's exactly that. I had removed devise confirmable so there's no longer a confirmation flow upon signup, but didn't remove the confirmed filter on the index page.

Comment: @Rebecca nice! just added a real answer, so we can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those users already "confirmed" in production database? You're applying a filtering in `where(confirmed: true)`, so if you can see them in the "show" view (which didn't apply the filter), maybe that's the reason.

The rest of the posted code seems fine. Alternatively, you may need to clean up the cache and restart the server.